# Creating urls with variables within them

Tags: variables, url, django-rest-framework

So I have a very fundamental understanding of django. I know that I can use a string like the one below in my urlpatterns to create a url like this example.com/test/2005/03.

```
url(r'^test/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/$', views.SuperView.as_view()),
```

But what if I wanted to add something before the test parameter of the uri? Is it possible to make a url that reads like this for a business that has multiple locations?

```
www.example.com/company_name/location_name/test/2005/01
```

I want to learn how to build a flexible service that can work for multiple companies and I want to specify which company and which location is accessing data through the company_name/location_name/ section of the uri. In the request I want to grab these variables and use them to perform a join query against my database in the views and models.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can do this using path variables. If I understand your question correctly, you simply can use some URL patterns in the controller. A simple Spring example would be

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{company}/{location}/employees", method =RequestMethod.GET)
public String test(@PathVariable("company") String company, @PathVariable("location")  String location) {
           //your code
}
```

Comment: would this be in views.py or is there a more elegant way to do this? All requests would have the /company/location. Is there a way to easily add this to the beginning of every request for that api?

Comment: So i looked up Spring and it honestly looks like you are mistaken on the programming language and framework in general. I am using python and a framework called django, Django does nto have a property called @RequestMapping, as far as I could tell when I looked it up on Google.

Comment: This you have to do in the controller. If you are getting the same url pattern you should be able to do this in the class level. So you don't need to catch the path variables in every method. I'm not sure how to do that in Python. But definitely there should be a way. Please refer [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/)

Comment: Yes, I have explained the scenario using Spring, but django also provides a  similar functionality. Please refer the above link I have provided. I think that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see a link. I get the basic idea behind it. Can you provide a link within your answer?

Comment: I have already looked through the documentation for the URL Dispatcher and URL Conf, and I sort of get it. The problem I am having is that I just don't understand how using regex in the parentheses is useful. Would I just use whatever is passed through the URL to do a join query.

Answer (score 0):

So this took a bit of messing around in Django with a test api project I decided to make.

Here are the contents of my urls.py file in my app.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/test/$', views.DuperView.as_view()),
    url(r'^test/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/$', views.SuperView.as_view()),
    url(r'^test/', views.TestView.as_view()),
]
```

At first I started by messing with adding the data behind the endpoint test/. The uri test/0000/00 (the second one) passes each additional component into the apiview as an argument (as shown below in my views.py code. Well if you move the compontents of the uri to where it is before the test/ endpoint it still passes that same information to the apiview in the same exact way. So you can do /0000/00/test/ and those components are still passed to our api view.

Here is my views.py file contents.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

class TestView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        an_apiview = [
            'this',
            'is',
            'a',
            'list',
        ]

        return Response({'http_method': 'GET', 'api_view': an_apiview})

class SuperView(APIView):
    # because our url is test/{year}/{month} in the urls.py file
    # {year} is passed to the view as the year argument
    # {month} is passed to the view as the month argument
    def get(self, request, year, month, format=None):
        an_apiview = [
            'this',
            'is',
            'a',
            'super',
            'list',
            ]

        return Response({'http_method': 'GET', 'api_view': an_apiview})


class DuperView(APIView):
# because our url is {year}/{month}/test/ in the urls.py file
# {year} is passed to the view as the year argument
# {month} is passed to the view as the month argument
    def get(self, request, year, month, format=None):
        an_apiview = [
            'this',
            'is',
            'a',
            'duper',
            'list',
            ]

        return Response({'http_method': 'GET', 'api_view': an_apiview})
```